# How to match a string pattern like AB12 with c# Regex

Tags: c#, regex

In detail, needs to match a string with the following pattern:

- Always starts with plain English letters (i.e. A-Z, a-z)
- The length of the above letter is between 1 to 3
- Followed by any numbers of which the first digit is not 0 (i.e. AB01 is *not* valid but AB1 *is*)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
[A-Za-z]{1,3}[1-9]\d*
```

which is a literal translation of your remarkably precise question.

Comment: Hmm... in most cases, the expression works fine, but seems to fail when it comes to 1AB12, which contradicts the first rule.

Comment: I was testing it on a program called Kodos, btw

Comment: @woodykiddy: Well, if you don't want it to start matching in the middle of a word, just add a `\b` to each end (though I can't remember if `\b` matches at the start and end of a string in .NET -- it should, but I think it might not. In which case, you could use `(?:^|\b)` at the beginning and `(?:$|\b)` at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Cameron is right, except you have to put in a starting limit. For future refernce, you should look into a good online regex tester.  I like [Derek Slager's](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx).

```
^[A-Za-z]{1,3}[1-9]\d*
```

if you want to match the whole line, and not just the beginning, then

```
^[A-Za-z]{1,3}[1-9]\d*$
```